# OneSignal SDK wants to delete all assets at import in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, onesignal

[image: Screenshot]

I downloaded OneSignal SDK from its official GitHub repository, when I try to import it into my unity project it shows this:
Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: Could you add the following details?
1. Version of Unity
2. Is this the first time adding OneSignal to your project? Or updating the SDK
3. Can you reproduce the problem on a new project?

Comment: I`m using Unity 2019.3. Yes, this was the first time. I didn`t try to import it into an empty project, instead, I opened an example project from OneSignal, and copied the folders from it into my project, and it was ok.